# T(n-1) + 1/lg(n) recurrence

Tags: computer-science, recurrence

I'm looking for an upper AND lower bound (or just a theta bound, for that matter).

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1/lg(n)
```

I'm studying for a test, and this is one of the practice questions I've been stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the following expansion will give you the appropriate hint:

T(n) =

= 1/lg(n) + T(n-1)

= 1/lg(n) + 1/lg(n-1) + T(n-2)

= 1/lg(n) + 1/lg(n-1) + 1/lg(n-2) + T(n-3)

= ···

= 1/lg(n) + ··· + 1/lg(n/2) + T(n/2)

= Theta(n/lg(n)) + T(n/2)

Now, use the Master theorem on this new recurrence.